# run scala-web project,postgresql permission denied to create extension "uuid-ossp"

Tags: postgresql, scala

ERROR: permission denied to create extension "uuid-ossp" suggest：Must be superuser to create this extension. [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42501], while trying to run this SQL script:

[error details:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJNAs.png)

[but there is no "default" database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1idi.png)

I use postgresql9.6.9.

Comment: is there any one,please?

Comment: please,some one can help me